# Is there a PS command/script that can retrieve Azure Key vaults certificates expiration date?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I'm trying to create a script that I can run every 3-4 weeks that can give me a report regarding Azure Key vaults Certificates expiration dates.

All I could find on the internet was about local certificates or SSL certificates.

Is it even possible to do something like this?

Or maybe there is an option in Azure itself to set up notifications about Certificates expiration dates?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, can you share with us what you've done already to look into this such as any code or even a thought process in what exactly has been attempted. SO isn't a code writing service so we won't be able to assist if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you try [Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate?view=azurermps-6.13.0)?

Comment: To be honest I'm not even sure where to start from. I don't expect anyone to write the script for me from zero. I just want to know if it is possible and if yes maybe just link me a an article with the main commands I need to use. Edit: boxdog not yet - but i will try it right now. Ty.

Comment: I made a bit of progress but since my PS skills are very low I am not sure how to continue. I got the commands : `Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "name"` What I am trying to do now is to get a list of all Certificates from all Vaults and create a table that will show the name/expireson/daysuntilexpiration.

Answer (score 0):

The [Az.KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-2.0.0) PowerShell module has a [Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate?view=azps-2.0.0) function that returns an object with an `Expires` property. If you are not familiar with the `Az` PowerShell module(s), which is the newer version of `AzureRM` please read the introduction on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-2.0.0) to make yourself familiar as you will need to authenticate to Azure, optionally select your subscription, etc. Installation of it should just be `Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber`. At this point I am assuming you are at least on PowerShell version 5.1.